# MapBox; Use style as tileset

Tags: mapbox

Is it possible to use a MapBox style as a tileset? I would like to add the style as a tile layer in QGIS.

I can access tiles from my tilesets in a browser.

http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/dbauszus.9ezmpldi/14/8187/5443.png?access_token={}

When I substitute the tileset map id dbauszus.9ezmpldi with my style map id dbauszus.cilusj60s00scc3lwa30nys2b I get {"message":"Tileset does not exist"}.

Is there any way to request tiles directly from a style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be quiet easily possible now.

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/dbauszus/cilusj60s00scc3lwa30nys2b/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={my access token}

I am 100% sure that this is a new feature which wasn't on my dashboard two months ago.

Great work MapBox. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to accomplish this by including your Mapbox username within the url. Documentation for the Mapbox API can be found [here](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/). The format for the URL should be:

```
http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{username.id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={your access token}
```

This [example](https://www.mapbox.com/help/georeferencing-imagery/) shows off using QGIS and Mapbox.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The example shows how to add a tileset. This is not the problem. I can access tileset as shown in the post. The problem is with accessing tiles from style, not a tileset.